# Libraries neccessary to install lua not installing

Tags: c++, lua

I am running Debian Jessie and i was trying to learn how to embed Lua as a scripting language into a c++ program, but when i use apt to install lua i do not get the libraries "lua.h", "luaxlib.h", or "lualib.h" and i haven't found any answers when going through forums and such. I have done both

```
sudo apt-get install lua50
sudo apt-get install lua5.2
```

and they say i already have them up to date and upgraded, but i do not get the lua C API which is what i need at this point. I also do not know the difference between those two packages so any explanation over that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: wow haha thank you i cant believe it was that simple and i missed it! i appreciate the quick response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lua.h`, `lauxlib.h`, and `lualib.h` are not "libraries" they are header files and they would be contained in the `-devel` versions of the packages.

You aren't missing "the lua C api" you are missing the header files you need to compile your own C code against the lua api (because you lack the definitions of the api functions, etc.).

The difference between those packages is the version of lua involved.

`lua50` is likely lua 5.0. `lua5.2` is going to be lua 5.2. They are (very) different versions of the language.

Comment: You should install whichever version(s) of lua you have reason to use.